# How to get and send all messages from the channel to channel?

Tags: telegram-bot, telethon, telegram-api

I have a code that can copy a message from one channel to another channel, but this code works only for "NewMessages", how to make this code to send all messages from the channel to another channel?

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

api_id = 
api_hash = ''

my_channel_id = -1001247324182
channels = [-100129537617]

client = TelegramClient('myGrab', api_id, api_hash)
print("GRAB - Started")

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    if event.message:
        await client.send_message(my_channel_id, event.message)
 
 
client.start()
client.run_until_disconnected()
```

So, it is possible to do this code to send all messages from the channel? Maybe, another library?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can [iter_messages](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) and forward it to new channel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: yes, thanks! But answer is unclear for another users :D

Comment: this is not an answer